# The currfile Package

Tags: currfile

I am using a number of input files within 2 directories:

`dirA/` which has a file `dirA/A.tex` which inputs `dirA/dirB/B.text`

I'm using `currfile` to print out the `currfiledir` which gives me

```
dirA/dirB
```

is there anyway I can make it just give me `dirB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the help of the [xstring](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package and its macro `\StrBehind`.

In your case, if `\currfiledir` returns `dirA/dirB/`, then

```
\StrBehind{\currfiledir}{/}
```

will return `dirB/`.

In fact the result is "all the stuff behind `/`"

If you also want to remove the trailing `/` you can use

```
\StrBehind{\currfiledir}{/}[\currfilesubdir]
\StrBefore{\currfilesubdir}{/}
```

In this way you first save the result of `\StrBehind` in the macro `\currfilesubdir` and then you use it as the argument of `\StrBefore` which does the opposite of `\StrBehind`. The result will be `dirB`.

---

Obviously this only works if you have your file in a subdirectory of second level like `dirA/dirB/`.

If your file is in a deeper subdirectory (let's say `dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/`, you can opt for one of the following solutions to automate the whole process.

1. **Print the subdirectory name *without* the trailing `/`**

   Add the following lines in your preamble:

   ```
   \newcommand{\currlastdir}{%
     \StrCount{\currfiledir}{/}[\numberofdirs]%
     \ifnum\numberofdirs=1\StrBefore{\currfiledir}{/}\else%
     \StrBehind[\numexpr\numberofdirs-1\relax]{\currfiledir}{/}[\currfilesubdir]%
     \StrBefore{\currfilesubdir}{/}\fi%
   }
   ```

   and then in your subdocument use

   ```
   \currlastdir
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   \currfiledir
   ```

   and you will get `dirD` printed.
2. **Print the subdirectory name *with* the trailing `/`**

   Add the following lines in your preamble:

   ```
   \newcommand{\currlastdir}{%
     \StrCount{\currfiledir}{/}[\numberofdirs]%
     \ifnum\numberofdirs=1\currfiledir\else%
     \StrBehind[\numexpr\numberofdirs-1\relax]{\currfiledir}{/}\fi%
   }
   ```

   and then in your subdocument use

   ```
   \currlastdir
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   \currfiledir
   ```

   and you will get `dirD/` printed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\def\currfiledir{dirA/dirB} % for example

\def\ignorefirstdir{\expandafter\ignorefirstdirA\currfiledir/\end}
\def\ignorefirstdirA#1/#2\end{\ifx^#2^\else\expandafter\ignorefirstdirB#2\end\fi}
\def\ignorefirstdirB#1/#2\end{#1}

Printing only second directory: \ignorefirstdir.
```